# Changing text with Labview Toggle switch?

Tags: labview

I'm new to Labview and was wondering if the following was possible:

Can you switch the same text box using a toggle switch? I have tinkered around and figured that I need the selector when displaying output but can't seem to get anywhere.

ex. When toggle switch is true = show a text on front panel that says on
When toggle switch is false = change the SAME text to off.

Answer (score 2):

While I reckon there is more to your question, without any constraints, this is this the easiest way: use a string indicator and give it a new value when the toggle switch changes position.

### Example

[image]

### VI Snippet

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer is good, but to be more precise consider using **select** instead of **case** structure. The **select** works lighter in LabVIEW.

In situations when you just have to pass this or that data (your case), not perform code (ex: Popup something in **true** case and enable a counter in **false** case) you should consider using selector, as in case structure you create additional tunnel, which can be avoided using Select.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the LabVIEW compiler will end up creating more or less identical code for the two examples - I don't think there's a data copying issue here, and in any case it's trivial for a small string. But the Select looks neater.

Comment: Agree for this particular case, the compiler will end up with the same code.  In general it is recommended to use Select to just pass data.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want some text next to the switch that changes to show the state of the switch, you can do this without any code:

- Right-click on the toggle switch and choose **Show > Boolean Text**.

You should now see the word `ON` or `OFF` in the middle of the switch.

- Right-click on it again and choose **Advanced > Customize…**.

LabVIEW will now open the control editor window. The first button in this window's toolbar looks like a spanner (wrench); click it and it should change to a pair of tweezers.

- Select the `ON` or `OFF` text and move it to where you would like it to be, relative to the switch itself.
- Close the control editor window. You can save the control as a separate file if you want to reuse it elsewhere, but if you don't it will still be saved as part of your VI.

You can edit the Boolean Text on your VI's front panel in the normal way. Note that clicking on the boolean text when the VI is running will operate the switch - you may or may not want that to happen. You could get round this by placing a transparent decoration box on top of the text.

All Boolean controls (I think) have a Boolean Text property, but not all of them have it visible by default.